# Website upgraded to 1.10.3 throws StrackOverflowException on UserPart ContentQuery. How to troubleshoot?

Tags: orchardcms

I inherited an Orchard project that started out in version 1.6 and was subsequently upgraded to 1.7, 1.8, 1.9 and 1.9.3 without issue. I have now taken steps to upgrade to 1.10.3. This involved changing the .NET framework version of my custom modules from 4.5.1 to 4.5.2 but didn't cause any issues. The solution builds without errors and I am able to run and browse the website anonymously. No errors or warnings appear in the logs.

However, when I try to log in as a user, I get w3wp exceptions and my local IIS goes down. Again, no errors are logged before this happens. When debugging, a StackOverflowException occurs on line 134 of `DefaultContentQuery.cs`:

```
var criteria = (CriteriaImpl)queryProvider.TranslateExpression(queryable.Expression);
```

which keeps getting called over and over by line 137 in `Orchard.Users.MembershipService` without ever resolving:

```
return _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query<UserPart, UserPartRecord>().Where(u => u.NormalizedUserName == lowerName).List().FirstOrDefault();
```

I realise that this is probably an issue with my particular project, but any suggestions on how to proceed with troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a longstanding unresolved issue in Orchard, caused by having a CommonPart on the User type: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/2192.

When a query is performed for a certain content type, Orchard creates a new instance of a content item of that type at some point. This triggers all the ContentHandlers associated with the type. When the CommonPartHandler is invoked and its OwnerId is 0, it attempts to set the current user as the owner, which causes an infinite loop when it happens in the GetUser() method upon logging in. The solution is to remove the CommonPart from your User type, if you don't need it, or change the source code of the CommonPartHandler to items of the User type.